# How to create 2 application domains for 2 different web applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to create 2 application domains for 2 different web applications?

Comment: you're going to need to clarify

Comment: I know how to create an appdomain in c-sharp and then assign an assembly to it, for example an exe file but how do I assign a web app to the newly created appdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cant create an app domain by ourselves.